# Average value by group

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have this query below which selects all the sectors and gets the value when the date falls on any of those 3 dates specified in the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT 
Sector
,Val
FROM [Consumption] upc
WHERE upc.PeriodStart = '2020-12-07 17:00:00' 
    OR upc.PeriodStart = '2021-01-07 17:30:00' 
    OR upc.PeriodStart = '2021-02-10 18:00:00'
```

Current Result:

```
Sector        Val
Retail        53.4
Retail        58.1
Retail        60.5
Commercial    58.2
Commercial    60.6
Commercial    53.5
```

How would I go about getting the average between the values grouped by the sectors multiplied by 2 so that the result will look like below?

Expected Result:

```
Sector        Val       AvTot
Retail        53.4      114.67
Retail        60.5      114.67
Retail        58.1      114.67
Commercial    58.2      114.87
Commercial    60.6      114.87
Commercial    53.5      114.87
```

Comment: Is there a reason to include `val` in group by?

Comment: Did you mangle your first query and accidentally omit the aggregate AVG? If not explain why it has a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: My mistake, it was part of a subquery originally it was not meant to be for this example. I have removed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A windowed `AVG()` returns the expected results:

```
SELECT Sector, Val, AVG(Val * 2) OVER (PARTITION BY Sector) AS AvgTotal
FROM (VALUES
   ('Retail',        53.4),
   ('Commercial',    58.2),
   ('Retail',        60.5),
   ('Commercial',    60.6),
   ('Commercial',    53.5),
   ('Retail',        58.1)
) [Consumption] (Sector, Val)
ORDER BY Sector
```

Result (without rounding and/or casting):

```
Sector     Val  AvgTotal
--------------------------
Commercial 58.2 114.866666
Commercial 60.6 114.866666
Commercial 53.5 114.866666
Retail     60.5 114.666666
Retail     58.1 114.666666
Retail     53.4 114.666666
```

Comment: Windowed AVG() works along with a subquery rather than explicitly specifying the values, but yes that also works

Comment: @mdbuzzer the explicitly specified values are just a way to present a data set without explicitly creating a table. If you want answers that always reference your tables, [help us out](https://sqlblog.org/ask) by creating an example table in a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk).